# In Next.js, how to route to page/index.tsx when app/page.tsx has occupied the root route "/"

Tags: next.js

I am new to Next.js, I tried an example.

The project structure is:

```
  src
    --app
      -- page.tsx
    --components
```

routing localhost:3000 goes to `app/page.tsx`. Now I add a page folder with an `index.tsx`

```
   src
     -- pages
       -- index.tsx
```

How would the app route to `pages/index.tsx` since `app/page.tsx` has already occupied the localhost:3000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have an `app/page.tsx` and a `pages/index.tsx` as Next.js won't know which one to use to render the `/` path. The two create a route using, respectively, the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) and [`pages`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) routers.

If you try, for example, to build your project while having the two files, you get this error:

> error Conflicting app and page file was found, please remove the conflicting files to continue:
> error   "pages/index.tsx" - "app/page.tsx"

So if you want to use `pages/index.tsx`, delete  `app/page.tsx`, and vice versa.